# The description for Event ID ( 0 )

Tags: .net, logging, windows-services, system.diagnostics

The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in Source ( .NET Runtime ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: ProcessName: MyService

ProcessId: 7600
Failed to initialize trace source..

---

On only one server i get this, it cannot log on the disk, 
permission are USERS 'FullControl'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the error commenting this.. it's a "source" in the config file.

```
<source name="System.Transactions" switchValue="None">
    <listeners>
      <add name="tx" type="System.Diagnostics.." initializeData="C:\Temp\trace.log" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
```